# What this running error means?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Hello, I`m trying to run a job in spring batch but its giving me this error which i dont know how to solve:

```
`$`  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC>java -jar C:\Workspacetest\testpro
    ject\target\ams-eod-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar copyJob 1 `$`

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainClassFromJar(LauncherHelper.java:399)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:463)
```

However this is my applicationcontext. can anyone help me regarding this error please?
few words to discribe what the job does, this job reads from a database some records and then it performs a calculation on each record (row * 3.75) and then update the record.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
     xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd">

<beans:bean id="itemReader" class="org.spr...JdbcCursorItemReader">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <beans:property name="sql" value="select * from Trans WHERE id =?"/>
    <beans:property name="rowMapper" ref= "CustomerCreditRowMapper"/>
    <beans:property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="idSetter"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionProcessor" class="">
    <beans:property name="targetObject" ref="Processing"/>
    <beans:property name="targetMethod" value="process"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jdbcWriter"                                
class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> 
    <beans:property name="sql" value="update Trans set (amount) values (?)"/>
    <beans:property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="idSetter"/>
</beans:bean> 

<step id="CopyFileStep">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="itemReader"
               processor="transactionProcessor"
               writer="jdbcWriter"
               commit-interval="10"/>
    </tasklet>
</step>

<job id="copyJob">
    <step id="step1" parent="CopyFileStep"/>
</job>

<beans:bean id="preparedStatementSetter"   
class="sa.com.anb.itg.dev.settlement.batch.Itemwriter"/>

<beans:bean id="idSetter" class="sa.com.anb.itg.dev.settlement.batch.idSetter"    
scope="step">
    <beans:property name="id" value="#{jobParameters[id]}"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="CustomerCreditRowMapper"     
class="sa.com.anb.itg.dev.settlement.batch.CustomerCreditRowMapper"/>

<beans:bean id="AmountToTransactionItemProcessor" 
    class="sa.com.anb.itg.dev.settlement.batch.AmountToTransactionItemProcessor">
        <beans:property name="TransactionDAO" ref="TransactionDAO"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="TransactionDAO" class="sa.com.anb.itg.dev.settlement.batch.TransactionDAO">
    <beans:property name="datasource" ref="dataSource"/>
</beans:bean>       

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
   <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
   <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.84.208:1556:pay10g" />
   <beans:property name="username" value="ams_recon" />
   <beans:property name="password" value="ams_recon" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jobRepository"
class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <beans:property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jobLauncher"
  class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <beans:property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" lazy-init="true">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: You control the code of that app, right?

Comment: yes i do control the app.

Comment: Paste the code for the `main()` method. Also, an excerpt of the most used class by it.

Comment: i have no main class because i`m running it through a commandLineJobRunner, i dont know if this is a correct way or not because i`m new to srping batch. please correct me if i`m wrong

Comment: please paste manifest for this jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, when launching an App you REALLY need a Main Class.

Spring Batch can provide one for you : CommandLineJobRunner.

In your example it seems that your are trying to execute your app like a regular one with the commandLine. Here Java try to locate you Manifest File because the JVM NEEDS a Main class and it's not able to find it in your JAR which cause your error.

It's not your app that you have to launch with the command line, it's the CommandLineJobRunner which provide a Main method able to launch your batch.
The documentation show how to use it : http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html#runningJobsFromCommandLine

Comment: No i dont have but based on what i`ve read, i dont need to have a main class since i`m going to run it in the CommandLineJobRunner. I`m not sure because I`m new to spring batch. Please couls you provide me with a sample main class is possible. i would be very thankful.

Comment: Thank you very much that was very helpful but the main class is not there which i`m looking for is removed. any tips if possible